# Type mismatch in set frame statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to use the Outlook View Control in Microsoft Access. As I understand it, this can only be used by embedding it in a Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame control.

After being unsuccessful, I downloaded a database from Experts Exchange that worked fine. When I tried to replicate it in my database I received a Type Mismatch error. I then imported the form from the database I had downloaded which was working correctly, but when I ran it in my database, I get the same type mismatch error.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim MyFrame As Frame
    Dim vc As viewctl

    Set MyFrame = Me.Frame0.Object
    Set vc = MyFrame!ViewCtl1

    With vc
        .Folder = "John Smith"
    End With

End Sub
```

The code is very simple, but I fail to understand what is causing the problem. The references have been added for Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library and Microsoft Outlook View Control. In fact, I have all of the references in the working database I downloaded together with others in my database.

The code is as follows:

The error throws up on `Set MyFrame = Me.Frame0.Object` as

> error 13 Type Mismatch.

The folder name is the name of a shared calendar.

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

The link to the database I downloaded is:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4617/Outlook-View-Control-OVC-part-two-Changing-folders-and-interacting-programmatically-Access-2007.html#comments

Comment: Make sure `Frame` is resolving to the correct type - if `Access.Frame` is a thing (IDK), then it takes precedence over `MSForms.Frame` because `Access` is higher in the reference priority (it's the host app, so you can't move it down). Try fully qualifying `Dim MyFrame As MSForms.Frame`.

Comment: Mathieu that is brilliant. Thank you so much. It is working perfectly now.

Comment: Cool! Posted as an answer, below - feel free to mark as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean `Frame` to refer to the MSForms type, then you may need to fully-qualify it:

```
Dim MyFrame As MSForms.Frame
```

In general, it's a good habit to fully-qualify types that have a name that may exist in more than just one referenced type library: if `Access.Frame` exists, then it has a higher priority in the resolution order (see ordering of libraries in the tools/references dialog), so an unqualified `Frame` would be implicitly `Access.Frame`, hence the type mismatch.